# Translation of interval

Tags: postgresql, datetime, translation, intervals, postgresql-8.4

There is maybe a way to translate automatically interval as it's shown by postgresql (e.g. "1330 days 10:54:54.266684") to other languages? For instance using locales, or other settings or I have to use replace, e.g. regexp_replace((now()-t.another_date)::text, 'day','dzień')?

Comment: You probably want `to_char`

Comment: At least don't use the expensive `regexp_replace` when you have no regexps in use, there is the normal `replace` function also. But usually the display semantics are done in the presentation layer, not in the database itself, if possible.

Comment: I use specific framework, which is very "close" to database, there is no mid-layer in between, so data as "3 days" just as it is are shown in browser. I'm not sure about simple replace, because of days & day -> I would rather avoid constructions like "3 dzieńs" with extra 's'

Comment: @CraigRinger - I see in to_char that I can get result like 'HH12:MI:SS' but I would prefer full names in other language. Is it possible as well?

Comment: @HWid While `to_char` supports localised strings and will respect `LC_TIME`, it doesn't have placeholders for joining-words like "days", so I think you're out of luck. It'd be a good feature to support things like `DAYS`, `MONTHS` as an interval-formatting placeholder for the localized word... perhaps suggest that to the pgsql-hackers mailing list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think no. sorry. day, month etc are field in type interval. it will be in English. like you don't expect use "vybrac" instead of select :)
But you can have [locale](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/locale.html) in time values, yes.

```
td=# set lc_time TO pl_PL;
SET
td=# SELECT to_char(to_timestamp (4::text, 'MM'), 'TMmon');
 to_char
---------
 kwi
(1 row)
```

So probably only option is replacing timestamp filealds values with polish names